# Deletion of author when submit the revised version of the submitted paper

Tags: publications

I have a question about the general regulation of VLDB for deletion of author when submit the revised version of the submitted paper (but the paper was rejected finally).

I found a link https://www.councilscienceeditors.org/resource-library/editorial-policies/sample-correspondence-for-an-editorial-office/addition-or-deletion-of-author-before-publication/ about making author changes before paper publication but not for my case.

Suppose our team (3 members) submitted a paper to VLDB, we revised the paper after received the comments from the reviewers.

We didn't include the work from one of the members in the revised version of the submitted paper.

Is it possible for us to remove this author from the paper when submit the revised version of the submitted paper?

What are the procedures required for such change?

Thank you very much!

Best Regards,

Chris.

Comment: Did you also remove his/her contribution from the whole paper (i.e. even from the original submitted draft = the revised paper doesn't have any input from the deleted author)?

Comment: Original Submitted Draft (3 authors) & its Revised Version (2 authors). Did you mean we could apply for deletion of author for the original submitted draft to VLDB first and then submitted the revised version to VLDB?

Comment: I was trying to say that it wouldn't be fair to remove the 3rd aut. from the paper if some of his/her contribution is still present in the revised manuscript. Although the content of the revised manuscript doesn't have input from the 3rd aut. the paper's core idea/concept/flow etc. might have been because of some of his/her work. In general, being an author doesn't specifically mean that you need to "write" a section or few pages. Sometimes, a notable contribution that is worthy of being an author can be through other things. You need to decide and see to what extent is the 3rd aut. involved.

Comment: How did the editor answer this question?  (You _did_ ask the editor this question, didn't you?)

Comment: By the way, what does "VLDB" stand for?

Comment: Yes, everything about the author proposed to be removed from the revised version of the submitted paper was completely removed.

Comment: No, I didn't. The case involved was related to VLDB 2014. Here, I just wanted to check if whether the "author changes" could be made to prevent any argument even this paper was rejected finally.

Comment: VLDB stands for Very Large Data Base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this third author willing to give up authorship?  If so, the third author should contact the editor and explain that they want their name taken off of the revised paper and explain why.  In my experience, this is not a problem if the departing author has requested that their name be removed from the paper.